# Oracle OCCI UString to std::wstring

Tags: c++, oracle, occi

In Oracle DB providers there is a term UString, which is used when dealing with UTF16 char set.

Here it is how it is defined:

```
typedef unsigned short  utext;
typedef std::basic_string<utext> UString;
```

My App uses wstring for unicode and as we know std::wstring wraps wchar_t, which is not unsigned short, but internal type for C++. I know that there is an option in VCproj C++ language setting whether to use wchar_t as an internal type of not, but I prefer to leave it as an internal type.

So my problem is how to use OCCI with OCCIUTF16 without having to cast every UString to wstring?